# Update object HTML while loading source files with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, document, getelementbyid

I am importing necessary files via jQuery, and I want to update some text to show which file is being loaded, but it seems that the imports are done before the text is ever updating, regardless of the specified order. However, the console logging updates on schedule, even though it's being called *after* the import statement. I've tried the text update call this way as well, but it didn't work either.

Here is a code excerpt:

```
var jsFiles = new Array('some js files');
var cssFiles = new Array('some css files');

for(var i = 0; i < jsFiles.length; i++) {
    $('#loadfile').text('imported js library `' + jsFiles[i]+'`');
    $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+jsFiles[i]+'"></script>');
    console.log('imported js library `' + jsFiles[i]+'`');
}

for(var i = 0; i < cssFiles.length; i++) {
    $('#loadfile').text('imported css library `' + cssFiles[i]+'`');
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="'+cssFiles[i]+'" />');
    console.log('imported css library `' + cssFiles[i]+'`');
}
```

I tried setting a timeout and I also tried setting a variable to true if the text has been updated and checking to see if that variable was true prior to importing files, but that just made the files not import.

I also tried using a `document.getElementById` call to update the text, but no dice there either. Is there something inherent in javascript that sets the priority of statements or am I just overlooking something?

Comment: The loop will be executed within milliseconds, match faster than all the scripts are loaded.  You won't see any noticeable changes to the element. The scripts are loaded asynchronously, the code does not wait until a script was loaded. Apart from that I don't understand what your problem is (if there is anything else).

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, Javascript runs on the GUI thread. While your script is being downloaded and read the GUI will not be updated until your script insertion is finished. The window.setTimeout will allow the gui to update before downloading/inserting the script.

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsFiles.length; i++) {
    $('#loadfile').text('imported js library `' + jsFiles[i]+'`');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+jsFiles[i]+'"></script>');
    }, 10);
    console.log('imported js library `' + jsFiles[i]+'`');
}
```

Source: [JavaScript seems to be executing code in wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696081/javascript-seems-to-be-executing-code-in-wrong-order)

Comment: Like I said, I tried using timeouts but they only broke my code further. When I tried your example, it says that one of my functions is not defined because it never imported it's parent file.

Comment: The javascript files still will be downloading asynchronously. So if the child javascript downloads before the parent this error will occur. Maybe look at the .getScript jQuery function to get the scripts. Then set a variable in the return function. don't continue loop until that variable is true. Example:
    $.getScript(jsFiles[i], function(){
      finished=true
    });